# I want to check this code for infinite looping line 21

Tags: python, while-loop, infinite-loop

it is a simple tik-tok game code in python, there seem to be an infinite loop but I can not spot it

```
while loc[:3]!='x'or 'o' | loc[3:6]!='x'or 'o' | loc[6:]!='x'or'o'| ((loc[0] and loc[3] and loc[6])!='x'or'o') | ((loc[1] and loc[4] and loc[7])!='x'or'o') | ((loc[2] and loc[5] and loc[8])!='x'or'o') | ((loc[2] and loc[4] and loc[6])!='x'or'o') | ((loc[0] and loc[4] and loc[8])!='x'or'o'): 
    keeping_turns=[]
    if len(keeping_turns)==0 or len(keeping_turns)%2==0:
        player=player_1
        symbol=symbol_1
    else:
        player=player_2
        symbol=symbol_2
            #result=resultglob
        result=input(' please ' +player+' insert your chosen location: ')
```

i expect to get to the last line, to input a value. but I get stuck in '*' and have to interrupt the kernel every time.`enter code here`

Comment: You are checking values in `loc` but never changing them inside the `while` block. As soon as the `while` executes there is no way to get out of it. This code essentially becomes `while True: ...`

Comment: I do not want to get out of it before the condition is met. all I want is to get to put my input in the last line for the while loop to keep checking the values in the list if they meet the condition or not. if I removed the indent in the last line, the program skips the if-else block in the middle.